# Autocomplete is not showing any CSS inside my asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, autocomplete

I have the following mark-up inside view to implement an auto complete:-

```
<input  name="term" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required= "Please enter a value."  data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "SecurityRole")"  />
```

and the following Script:-

```
 $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({
            source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000


              });

    });
```

in addition to that I have reference the following ui and scripts:-

```
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",            
                  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",            
                  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"     

     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
 "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

but currently the auto complete will not have any background color on the returned items , Also I will get the item displayed twice on my view (on inside the text while the other on the left hand side f the screen) as follow:-

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @ChepA See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34637859/)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. Using [this article](http://benscheirman.com/2009/04/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-with-asp-net-mvc/) as reference (FYI, it was hard to read), I was able to develop the following code:

```
//NOTE: I let jQuery UI populate these class names, so this may be different for you

// the class attributed to the autocomplete unordered list 
.ui-autocomplete { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none; // gets rid of the bullet points
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    background-color: #fff; // provides a background for the autocomplete returned items
    width: 500px; // it was necessary for me to set the width
}

.ui-autocomplete li {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
}

// to distinctly see which returned item is selected/hovered over
.ui-autocomplete .ui-state-focus { background-color: #66afe9; } 

// to hide the lower left text
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none; }
```

And the result:

[image: Autocomplete UI w/ CSS]